# React - split JSX into new line, only on small screen

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm looking to render a line of text that breaks into a new line, while only on a small size screen, in React.

My end goal is for this subtext to look something like `Available: 4-9PM` on a screen size of medium or higher, but on a small screen:

```
Available:
4-9PM
```

I typically use tailwind for inline CSS styling, so normally I would use `className='hidden md:block'` on a `div` to have an element hidden, but show at a certain size, however, I am not sure how to encorporate that with a line break. I tried adding `${<br />}` to the subtext variable, but that just added `[object OBJECT]` to the subtext. Thoughts? I've included relevant snippets below.

```
const options = servicePeriod => {
   const startTime = servicePeriod.startTime
   const endTime = serviceperiod.endTime
   subtext = `Available ${startTime}-${endTime}`

   return [
     {
       subtext: subtext
     }
   ]
}

return (
   <div>
      <OptionGroup
         options={options(servicePeriod)}
      />
   </div>

)
```

Comment: you can probably style it using: `flex-wrap: wrap` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Answer (score 0):

Returning a string may not adjust as per our requirement, hence we need to return a < div > instead

```js
const options = servicePeriod => {
  const startTime = servicePeriod.startTime
  const endTime = serviceperiod.endTime
  subtext = `<div>
                <div className="inline-grid">Available:</div><div className="inline-grid">${startTime}-${endTime}</div>
            </div>`

  return [{
    subtext: subtext
  }]
}
```

```css
.inline-grid {
  display: inline-grid;
}
```